# Automatic PagingAndSortingRepository for @Entity in some packages

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

How can I expose all entities decorated with @Entity in a specific package as rest services without creating an interface public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository for each such entity. In this doable?

Answer (score 0):

**You cant.**

It's like asking a person to do a car. You cannot do a car. you can do some functions in the car like, accelerate or break.

---

According to `spring-data-rest` you have to create the repositories for the framework to identify the rest resources.

Refer http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Further more, an entity is a data wrapper, while the repository is a function wrapper for that entity. You can only expose a set of functions (ie like CRUD). You cannot expose a bold entity by itself. In other words, what actually can you expose in an entity via a REST.